# strange square glyph appearing in Chrome for Windows

Tags: google-chrome, webfonts, text-rendering

Chrome for Windows (v58) seems to add a glyph at the end of a h3 heading.
This square is also seen in the inspector but not in the source code.

It seems like Chrome isn't rendering the font completely as it should? 
I'm using TT Hazelnuts from myfonts here.

There is no character missing from my line so doens't seem to be a special char issue or something.

The font is used throughout the site but it seems to only happen on some headers. Also other browsers don't have problems displaying the text correctly.

Changing text-rendering settings in CSS doesn't make a difference.

The site can be found at http://dev.everywhere.consulting  (until is goes live)

[image: square character]

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this by copying the text out of your editor, pasting it into the URL bar in Chrome on Windows (this will show you the strange square glyph), delete the square glyph there in the URL bar, then copy the text back into your editor.

Oddly enough, even source control will recognize the change but it won't appear to look any different.

Here I am doing it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPK0y.gif